# Motley Fool US v UK?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, websites

Does anyone know the relationship between the Motley Fool US and the Motley Fool UK?

A few years ago, fool.co.uk was a lively web site with very active forums.
Then it changed into something that looks like yet another money making wise enterprise...

Are they now different companies with different ethos?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [How can I tell what is “real” Motley Fool advice?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/54256/10997)

Comment: Good question. I can’t give a fully informed answer but what I do know is that when the fool.co.uk forums closed down in 2017 the majority of active users migrated to a new domain, lemonfool.co.uk, which seems to be run on a volunteer led basis i.e. no business model just a place to continue the forum.

Comment: You are right. 
I discovered that since and the forums seem very good. AND to be entirely honest, it was the support for fool.co.uk that told me (very quickly) so my "judgment" might have been a bit hasty...